# WordWrap in "connected" LinearLayout do not work

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, word-wrap

I don't understand why the wordwrapping in my sample do not work.

The XML describes "one line" of a vertical `LinearLayout`, which will be filled at runtime.
The line consists of a `checkbox` followed by two columns. The first column is a vertical `LinearLayout` with two `TextView`s inside (word wrapping is here fine). The second column is a `LinearLayout` with only one `TextView` (word wrapping does not work).

If the text of second column grows the first column shrinks to a small "one letter" column and the second do not wrap his long text. But the second is defined also to use wordwrapping...

Does anyone know a solution of this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/linearLayout2">
            <TextView
                android:text="A long long long long text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:singleLine="false" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:singleLine="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
            <TextView
                android:text="Another long long text... please wrap!!"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:singleLine="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have android:singleLine set to "False" in all of your text views.  If you want one of them not to wrap set it to "True"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: They should share the whole width, therefore i used singleLine=false for all.
My hope is: If both columns have "long text" to display, both should use wordwrapping to share the width (50/50 or so).

Comment: Single line has nothing to do with the width, if you want it to take up the whole width you should set android:layout_width="match_parent" and make sure the parent layouts are the same.  The single line attribute simply means "wrap the text or not".  Beware if you set it to true and there is not enough screen space it will truncate the string.

Comment: I have changed all layout_width to "match_parent". Now the checkbox and the following first column are invisible. The last (second) column uses the whole width.
I want them to share the width, so all three parts should be in one line. Checkbox-ColumnA-ColumnB. And if useful the columns wrap text to reach this goal.

Comment: You should read this blog.  http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/  Also your original question was why is the text wrapping.  The answer to that question is that SingleLine needs to be set to true to prevent any wrapping.

Comment: No. You misunderstood me. I know why the column wraps. They have to wrap, so they can share the width and show their content. If they cant wrap -> content will be cut off. They have to wrap.
The problem is: only one wraps (the first)! Not both. If both wraps all is fine!

Comment: I need more buddy, and I am guessing that is why it is only me answering.  Perhaps take a screenshot and post it up so we can see what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry i attempted to upload a picture... but my reputation is to less to do so. I need more than 10 points to enable uploading pictures.
Please... give me the missing four points :) ... thx all